# Direct & Indirect (Kohn-Sham) band gap for $\rm MgS$

Tags: electronic-band-theory, density-functional-theory

I recently performed a groundstate calculation for $\rm MgS$ using the self-consistent Kohn-Sham equation with LDA exchange-correlation. $\rm MgS$ has an FCC crystal structure with two atoms per (non-orthogonal) primitive cell. If I consider this primitive cell as my simulation domain, I end up with an indirect bandgap $(\Gamma-X)$  of 2.6 eV which agrees with existing literature. However, if I use an FCC 8-atom orthogonal unit cell, I get a direct bandgap $(\Gamma-\Gamma)$ of 2.6 eV again. Is this normal behaviour?

TLDR: KS-DFT indirect band-gap for primitive cell but direct bandgap for a supercell.

Comment: If these two choices describe the same structure the andere should be close to identical.

Comment: There is a proposal for a [Materials Modeling SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=ZWYwMTRmNzY5MTMxOTM4MjA5YTUyYmMzMmMzZDY2YzE4ZDMzYzQwNzdlNDVhYjllNWMxYmE0M2M2YWVmN2I2OMOoEgRdkZRPdG-_W7eJR3cVm9VRoMP_qteTvZIeIBpn0) which has a large proportion of experts from the field and questions like these will get more activity there when the site goes live. Do consider committing to it and being a part of the site building process.

Comment: I agree with @rashid, 5 months is long to not get an answer, you can copy and paste here: https://materials.stackexchange.com now that Materials.SE is live.